# MVC4, public virtual ICollection, how to set sort order

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have an MVC4 Project using Code First EF 5.

I have Models using public virtual ICollection and I want to set the sort order of how the items in these collections appear.

For example:

Say I have an Orders Model with:

```
public class Order
{
 public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and an OrderItems Model with:

```
public Class OrderItem
{
 public int ID;
 public string name;
 public decimal price;
}
```

and I want to set the Order of the OrderItem collection for each order to appear in descending price order. How would I go about that? Or, in fact, is it possible?

I have tried adding:

```
 this.Items.OrderByDescending(OrderItem,"price");
```

To the Order Model Constructor (fat models, skinny controllers ?)

I have also tried adding this to the Controller Action and to the View, none of which have worked.

I'm guessing there may be some way of doing this in DbContext but have to confess I'm a bit lost.

UPDATE: I've tried the following solutions as per suggestions so far but to no avail.

```
    private ICollection<OrderItem> _Items;
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> Items
    {
        get { return _Items.OrderByDescending(item => item.Price).ToList(); }
        set { _Items = value; }
    }
```

this produced this error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Do I need to add something to the Constructor?

I also tried adding a Constructor in the Model and the following:

```
public OrderItem()
{
this.Items = this.Items.OrderByDescending(i => i.Price).ToList();
}
```

This had no effect whatsoever.

I also tried:

```
this.Items = this.Items.OrderByDescending(OrderItem, "price").ToList();
```

Which produces the error "OrderItem is a type but is used like a variable".

Any ideas folks?

OK. I've just added this to the Details Method in my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
  order.Items = order.Items.OrderByDescending(item => item.price).ToList();         
}
```

Which worked. I would still like to know if possible why the get; set; solution didn't work just for future reference though. Has the difference between Lazy, Eager, and Explicit Loading got any relevance here also?

Thanks very much.

OK So I have tried Ken4z suggestion and added:

```
public Order()
{
_Items = new List<OrderItem>();
}
```

This prevents any errors, but does not actually load any items when the action is called in the controller. Might be a dumb questions but I'm going to ask it anyway in the line:

```
set { _Items = value; }
```

Isn't it the case that the constructor is now passing **value** as A List Of OrderItem with nothing in it? Trying to completely grasp this. So thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.Items.OrderByDescending(OrderItem,"price");
```

LINQ methods return a new instance, so you must *set* this result:

```
this.Items = this.Items.OrderByDescending(OrderItem, "price").ToList();
```

Note the `ToList()` since the result is `IEnumerable<T>` and `ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>` but `IEnumerable<T>` is not of `ICollection<T>`. `List<T> : ICollection<T>`.

You could also use a "cleaner", type-safe version of the LINQ method:

```
this.Items = this.Items.OrderByDescending(i => i.price).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var orderedItems = Items.OrderByDescending(item => item.price);
```

EDIT 1:

Based on David's comment, I am interpreting "Set" to mean, you want the accessor for the Items collection to return in descending order by price by default.  In that case you will need to implement the getter.

```
public class Order
{
    private ICollection<OrderItems> _items;
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItems> Items 
    {
        get{ return _items.OrderByDescending(item => item.price); }
        set{ _items = value; }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:
Thank you David for pointing out the error.

```
public class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        _items = new List<OrderItems>();
    }

    private ICollection<OrderItems> _items;
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItems> Items 
    {
        get{ return _items.OrderByDescending(item => item.price).ToList(); }
        set{ _items = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not explain how to SET the property.

Comment: I don't understand your criticism, the last line of your answer does the same thing except converts it ToList();

Comment: This assigns the result to a variable, but the question is how to assign it to the Items property in the class. Do that and I'll happily reverse my vote.

Comment: This will not compile, because `IEnumerable<T>` is not of `ICollection<T>` - you must convert it to an `ICollection<T>` such as `List<T>`

Comment: Ah. Good point. Should have put it in VS before posting.  I do think that putting the logic in the getter (or setter) as opposed to just setting this.Items is better so that any classes that use Items will get it in the desired order. Alternatively, you could put it in the setter if you want to use the ordered items within the class.

Comment: I now get this error - "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source." Triggered here -  get{ return _items.OrderByDescending(item => item.price).ToList(); } any ideas please?

Comment: You probably just need to initialize your _items array in the class constructor.  I'll edit the post to demo.

Comment: Thanks ken4z I tried that and unfortunately while there is no longer an error there are no items either, have edited question.

Comment: Correct. You are creating an empty list, so the behavior is expected.  You need to populate that list with some values.

Comment: OK, so it's becoming a bit clearer now. Where would it be best practice to populate the List? I a Method added to the Model or inside the Controller Action? Thanks very much again for your time. Also could you provide an example please?

Comment: That is a philosophical question that depends on your architecture, size and scale of the app, and opinions of those you work with among other things.

Answer (score 1):

If you end up needing sorted ICollection nav properties frequently, you can always add something like:

`[NotMapped]
public IList<OrderItem> ItemsSorted {get {return Items?.OrderBy(p=>p.price).ToList(); }}`

to your domain entities, that way you don't have to constantly sort stuff explicitly when you go to use it in controller or other code.